# How do I switch kernel version at /lib/modules/

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I have a software installed and after contacting their support they asked me to downgrade the kernel

I used uname -r and the current version is 4.15.0-200-generic.
I checked /lib/modules
I have: 4.15.0-197-generic  4.15.0-200-generic

How do I downgrade it to 4.15.0-197-generic? and how do I prevent it from updating? thank you.

Comment: *I checked /lib/modules I have: 4.15.0-197-generic 4.15.0-200-generic* - is this the only directory over there? It can't be. You could try rebooting and selecting a proper kernel version.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I think that's two directories - one for the current kernel (`-200`) and one for the previous (`-197`)

Comment: the software company asked you to **downgrade!!** a 5 year old kernel that's almost at the end of its standard LTS life?

Comment: @JaromandaX I’ll almost guarantee it’s an SBC or embedded system with a custom build that the OEM has never properly upgraded...